# Use promise when keydown is pressed too long

Tags: angular

I have a problem with this keydown.

I use angular to render image. When I pressed and hold keydown. Maybe because keydown fire event consecutive so my render method execute not faster than keydown event fire.

This is my code

```js
 @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (CommonVariables.isFullImage) { return; }

    /// case increase slice value.
    if (event.keyCode === CommonVariables.keycodePagingDown && this._isActivePanel) {
      let lastImage = this.currentTileLayout + this.currentSlice;
      if (this.currentSlice < this.maxListImage && lastImage < this.maxListImage) {
        this.currentSlice++;

        let tileInfo;
        this.tileViewChildern.forEach((component, index) => {
          tileInfo = this._tileList[this.currentSlice + index].Clone();
          tileInfo.listIndex = this.currentSlice + index;
          tileInfo.index = this._panelIndex + (index + 1);
          component.changeTileSlice(tileInfo);
        });
      }
    }
    // case decrease slice value.
    else if (event.keyCode === CommonVariables.keycodePagingUp && this._isActivePanel) {
      if (this.currentSlice > 0) {
        this.currentSlice--;

        let tileInfo;
        this.tileViewChildern.forEach((component, index) => {
          tileInfo = this._tileList[this.currentSlice + index].Clone();
          tileInfo.listIndex = this.currentSlice + index;
          tileInfo.index = this._panelIndex + (index + 1);
          component.changeTileSlice(tileInfo);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Can i use promise to handle flow run code?

Somebody help me how to handle keydown fire event after my method finish execute?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to use Observable in such situations. You have operator there [debounce time](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime) that perfectly fits your situation operator. Operator will take value only after 2 sec after previous You can configure it. So it will ignore jam keys.

Observable.from(event).debounceTime(2000).subscribe((event) => logic here)